# ASP.net page Authorization based on Network User

Tags: asp.net

I am building a web application for internal use
this application will be deployed on the internet but only employees should be able to access it.

How to know what is the network user id that is accessing the web page?
so I can authorize them to access one page and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in your Web.config file where authentication mode is set to Forms; replace that with the following lines:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">

</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Use the following line in your aspx page (code behind) to get the user name

```
User.Identity.Name
```